# Terraform - Iterate over a map of Objects in a Template to generate different yaml files

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I need to generate around 50 YAML files. Most of the content in the YAML is constant, only `name`, and `port` changes. I am using `Terraform v1.2.2`. I request you to help me correct my issue or suggest an alternate idea/solution achieve my goal

`netwrokfile.yaml` after generation

```
    apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
    kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
    metadata:
      name: web-policy # Changes
    spec:
      action: allow    
      rules: 
      - to:
        - operation:
            ports: ["9080", "8080"] # Changes from each application may have one or two or three ports.
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: web-policy # Changes
```

`networkfile.yaml.tpl`

```
    apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
    kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
    metadata:
    %{~ for sName, sPort in zipmap(sName, sPort) ~}
      name: ${sName}
    spec:
      action: allow
      rules:
      - to:
         - operation:
           ports: ${sPort}
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: ${sName}
    %{~ endfor ~}
```

`main.tf` in my module

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "istio-config" {
   manifest = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/networkfile.yaml.tpl",
   {
     sName =  [for v in var.serviceName: v.sName]
     sPort =  [for v in var.serviceName: v.sPort]
   }
    )
  }
```

`main.tf` calling my module

```
module "authorization_policy" {
  source = "../../modules/GlobalNetworkPolicy"

  serviceName = var.serviceName
}
```

Myy `variable.tf`

```
variable "serviceName" {
type = map(object({
  sName  = string
  sPort = list(string)
}))
default = {
  test-vm1 = {
    sName  = "web-policy"
    sPort = ["8080", "8081"]
  },
  test-vm2 = {
    sName  = "db-policy"
    sPort = ["8080", "8081", "443"]
  }
}
}
```

With the above code, I get the below error

```
can't unmarshal tftypes.String into *map[string]tftypes.Value, expected map[string]tftypes.Value
```

I tried using the solution mentioned here ([Terraform - Iterate over a List of Objects in a Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64651270/terraform-iterate-over-a-list-of-objects-in-a-template)). But it didn't help and it gives me the same error.

I also tried (https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) it give me a completely different error

```
Call to function "templatefile" failed: ../../modules/GlobalNetworkPolicy/templates/networkfile.yaml.tpl:5,3-4: Unsupported operator; Bitwise operators are not supported. Did you mean boolean NOT ("!")?,
│ and 4 other diagnostic(s).
```

Below is the complete error - Fixed by adding yamlencode

```
╷
│ Error: Failed to extract "manifest" attribute value from resource configuration
│
│   with module.authorization_policy.kubernetes_manifest.istio-config,
│   on ../../modules/GlobalNetworkPolicy/main.tf line 2, in resource "kubernetes_manifest" "istio-config":
│    2:    manifest = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/networkfile.yaml.tpl",
│    3:    {
│    4:      serviceName = var.serviceName
│    5:    }
│    6:     )
│
│ can't unmarshal tftypes.String into *map[string]tftypes.Value, expected map[string]tftypes.Value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply your code as:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "istio-config" {
   manifest = yamldecode(templatefile("${path.module}/templates/networkfile.yaml.tpl",
   {
     serviceName = var.serviceName
   }
    ))
  }
```

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
%{ for k, v in serviceName }
  name: ${v.sName}
spec:
  action: allow
  rules:
  - to:
     - operation:
       ports: ${jsonencode(v.sPort)}
selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: ${v.sName}
%{ endfor }
```

Comment: I have updated the code as you suggested, I still get the same error. `can't unmarshal tftypes.String into *map[string]tftypes.Value, expected map[string]tftypes.Value`

Comment: @Eva The template is definitely correct. What is the full error message? Which line it occurs at?

Comment: I have pasted the complete error at the end of the question

Comment: @Eva You can try with `yamldecode` as in the updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! I don't see that error now. I got another I think that is related to my access to eks cluster

Comment: it is only creating one Kubernetes resource `test-vm2` and it's not creating `test-vm1`. I added `for _each` above the manifest line and it still creates one resource.

Comment: @Eva " I added for _each above the manifes" This is a new issue. My answer correctly address the original problem that you reported with template parsing errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245613/discussion-between-eva-and-marcin).

Comment: thanks, I was able to get it working.